# Linux kernel and headers do not install on a VPS system

Tags: 14.04, kernel, dpkg, vps

At this point all I'm trying to do is update my headers on fresh Ubuntu 14.04:

```
root@invoke:~# uname -a
Linux invoke 2.6.32-042stab094.7 #1 SMP Wed Oct 22 12:43:21 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@invoke:~# uname -r
2.6.32-042stab094.7

root@invoke:~# cat /etc/lsb-release  
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu  
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04  
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty  
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

This command shows error:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Full log can be found in the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DyPBsPZx.

Once it starts, I have to do a fresh install.

If any information more is needed please don't hesitate to ask, if someone wants to teamview/remote I'm fine with that as well.

Comment: Are you trying to update to 3.13.0-53?

Comment: I've tried 3.13, 3.16, 3.19 No matter how which one I try it kicks back the same reply. At this point just using; linux-generic

Comment: What OS is installed? Is it Ubuntu? Which version? Please add `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: `root@invoke:~# cat /etc/lsb-release    
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu    
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04    
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty    
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"` (its in the tags)

Comment: And haw did it happen to have that kernel?

Comment: Came default from the VPS. (they have no idea whats going I swear, I've asked and opened close to 8 tickets concerning this. I don't know why they won't just get the new download.)

Comment: You can't update kernel on VPS. You can do it in some VPS control panel, if there is one, or contact the support.

Comment: Please make it an Answer so I can select this.

Comment: @Pilot6: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby Done....

Comment: @Pilot6: me too!  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases you can't upgrade linux kernel if you are using a system provided by VPS.

If there is an option in VPS control panel, then do it there.

Otherwise contact VPS technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to purge un-configured kernels and fix the package dependency problems:

```
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-generic
sudo dpkg -P linux-generic
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CB7VTBrM Looks like it may have some useful information in it. Didn't bother running the last two. -f pushing back same error as first run.

Comment: root@invoke:/# cd /boot  
root@invoke:/boot# ls  
grub   its not full.

Comment: sudo update-grub  
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of   `/vz/private/37783'. And this is as far as I've gotten, I have no idea where to go from here